# Is there an efficient way to get "Get-ComputerInfo data" in Powershell/.net

Tags: .net, powershell

Hey there hope everyone is having a good day! :)

I am currently learning to use some Powershell/.NET for a popup that shows basic info about a device.

For example "Get-ComputerInfo -Property CsModel" get's the devices model name/number.
Problem is if I put this data somewhere and print it out later it will be:

"@{CsModel=HP ZBook 15u G6}"

Is there a short way to only get the name itself?

Comment: If you execute `Get-ComputerInfo` you get an object with properties for each piece of information. If you add `-Property CsModel` you get an object with only that/those property/-ies set. You can thus get the model name like this: `(Get-ComputerInfo -Property CsModel).CsModel`

Comment: Are you asking how to get `HP ZBook` only? Or how to only get `HP ZBook 15u G6` without the `@{CsModel...}` part?

Comment: What Lasse is using is referencing the value of that property using *dot notation*. Using the *grouping* operator `(...)`, it enumerates all available properties which you can then dot reference. The other option is piping to `Select-Object`: `Get-ComputerInfo -Property CSModel | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CSModel`. I'd suggest creating a function to list what you need querying different classes from the CIM.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you for the easy solution!, at first it seemed kinda weird to me but I think i get it now why it has to be this way.
Thanks for your reactions guys!